# Change Basic-Slider with text as navigation other than numbers

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider, nivo-slider

I am looking for a slider which has a feature to add slide name in navigation rather than Numbers as Navigation

Below is simple jQuery Slider http://basic-slider.com/

I would appreciate if some can tell me if i can modify this slider so that i can replace bullets nav with Slide Name and have the same functionality

`Slide 1`  `Slide 2`  `Slide 3`  `Slide 4`

`OnMouse` hover slide should change to appropriate slide & `onMouse Click` it should go to a particular link.

Can same be done with Nivo slider

Comment: Unfortunately you need to edit the script to add the needed features. Should we make the editet version?

Comment: I would appreciate if some can help me with this as i am more of a developer who can do lit bit of scripting not to this extend. I am looking for solution so far i am not lucky.. Even if a slider with similar feature with be handy as i am open to use other sliders also

Comment: Please try to do it yourself first, and show us the code you tried if it fails.

Comment: I think this can help me http://www.metaphorcreations.com/nivo-slider-and-custom-links/

Comment: hey I made [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dEsWp/) for  everyone who want to help.

Comment: I've added the `Slide 1` `Slide 2` `Slide 3` `Slide 4` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Slider navigation use of text caption, not number:**

```
  <ul class="bjqs">
      <li title="Slide 1"> ... </li>
      <li title="Slide 2"> ... </li>
      <li title="Slide 3"> ... </li>
  </ul>
```

Javascript edit row #478 change this

```
  var slidenum    = key + 1,
```

with this:

```
  var slidenum    = $(slide).attr('title') === undefined ? key + 1 : $(slide).attr('title'),
```

**Click and hover functionallity:**

Javascript add as row #56:

```
  captionUrlArray : [] //Url for each of the captions
```

Javascript add as row #488:

```
   var newUrl = settings.captionUrlArray[key];
```

Javascript edit row #495 change this

```
  marker.on('click','a',function(e){
```

to this:

```
  marker.on('mouseover','a',function(e){
```

**Do not forget to set captionUrlArray when calling the slider library!!! **

```
  $('#banner-slide').bjqs({
        animtype      : 'slide',
        height        : 320,
        width         : 620,
        responsive    : true,
        randomstart   : true,
        captionUrlArray: [ "http://google.com", "", "http://example.com" ]
      });
```

The final working script is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/dEsWp/4/